# How to pre-fill input type time

Tags: angular

```
<input type="time" name="title" [(ngModel)]="settingsData.active_from" class="form-control" value="8.45">
```

I tried to enter the default value in input type time but it does not show anything:
[image: See Output Image]

I had tried putting default value by placing `8:45` in the placeholder attribute too but it does not show anything it's just blank.

Comment: Can you share what code you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried putting value in value attribute like value="11:45" and in placeholder attribute too, as placeholder="11:45" and also used [(ngModel)]="selectedTime" and given value "11:45" to it in my component.ts as suggested below by Mikkel Christensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Input Type Time

There appears to be two things wrong with your code currently.

1. Your input is formatted wrong. It must be a string in the `HH:mm` format, while you have set a default of `H:mm`
2. Your value property will be overwritten by the value you provide in your `[(ngModel)]` binding, so setting the value property in this instance will do nothing as the value will be overwritten by your ngModel binding.

**Example**

```html
<input type="time" [(ngModel)]="selectedTime">
```

```js
@Component()
export class MyExampleComponent {
 selectedTime = "08:45";
}
```

#### More Information

[MDN on Input Time Formatting (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format)

Comment: thanks for the solution but it does not seem to be working in my case. i am still getting nothing on my input type time.

Comment: Then there must be something else wrong with your code as this solution does work, at least in both Chromium and Firefox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rziu11?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you so much. i reviewed my code and realized i was storing in H:mm.I used [value]=HH:mm instead of [(ngModel)] and it worked for me. Thank you for your help